# VoIP PBX dilemma

Tags: voip, pbx

Our phones are currently provided through a local hosted VoIP company and it isn't working all that great.  As a result, we have decided to move to a local PBX server and bring a few PSTN lines to our offices.

Through our current solution, we have a full deployment of phones (NEC DT730) that we own and would like to reuse in a new system if at all possible.  Our current telephony provider has given us a quote for an NEC Univerge SV8100 based system but I'm not ready to take anything they say at face value and I can't find anything more than a vague sales brochure on NEC systems

I've looked into other systems to see if something else would suite our needs (two locations and a total of about 8 handsets at each location) but am just getting more confused as I'm also new to telephony.

Is NEC a good vendor?  Would a 3CX or Cisco based solution work better?  Time and ease of implementation is definitely a major factor in this decision.

Answer (score 2):

NEC has been selling PBX's for awhile and can safely be considered a "name brand" vendor. NEC sells through authorized resellers (as do most "traditional" PBX vendors) and you're not going to find much direct-to-consumer sales collateral or technical specs at all. That's typical of the industry, unfortunately.

The meat of your question, though, sounds like one of soliciting a suggestion for a particular phone system. I don't know that Server Fault is necessarily the right venue for such a solicitation. I definitely do know that there isn't enough information in your question to make an intelligent suggestion.

I'd recommend finding some local telephony vendors, giving them your specs (number of handsets, location and number of PSTN lines, desires for voicemail / unified messaging, type and usage characteristics of the connectivity between the remote offices), and working with them to get quotes. This is probably the quickest route to getting an answer (since you say that time is a major factor). If you can, get references from companies who worked with each vendor and who have the hardware the vendor is quoting and talk to them about their experience with the vendor and the hardware.